# What's the difference between using CRFClassifier (or NERClassifierCombiner) directly, compared to a "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner" pipeline?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm trying to perform NER on a set of volumes containing pages of text. I started out with creating a [`tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner`](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/dependencies.html) pipeline. With the default settings, on a 16 core machine, it takes about **5 minutes** to process a volume of 1,360 pages (parallelism manually controlled, not using the `threads` property - it is much faster this way).  Given that the goal is to process potentially thousands of volumes, this was deemed to be too slow. Another experiment involved trying to turn off various NER aspects by setting `ner.useSUTime` and `ner.applyNumericClassifiers` to `false`. This did not seem to improve the processing speed in any significant fashion. I was not able, however, to turn off the `TokensRegexNERAnnotator` that the pipeline employed. I tried setting `ner.regex` to `false` but that didn't seem to work. Not sure which property (if any) controls whether this annotator is enabled or not.

I then decided to use `NERClassifierCombiner` directly, loading the same 3 models (for English) that the pipeline was loading. Running on the same volume, this proved to be significantly faster. It processed the whole volume in about **15 seconds**. When comparing the resulting entities, they're mostly the same, save for the ones generated via the `TokensRegexNERAnnotator` from the pipeline, which I did not add (nor need) here.

For both approaches the unit of processing is a page of text. The pipeline uses `Annotation(pageText)` while the direct classifier uses `classify(pageText)`.

**Main questions** are: how do these two approaches differ? Is the sentence splitting and tokenization done the same way in both approaches?

Other questions:

1. is it possible to turn off `TokensRegexNERAnnotator` when using the pipeline?
2. are the `pos` and `lemma` annotators needed for NER? [Documentation](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#pos) seems to suggest that the answer is `no`. If they are not required, why are they [listed as dependencies](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/dependencies.html)?

Comment: Found an interesting comment in [`RegexNERSequenceClassifier.java` line 228](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/ede61e67b29405db050538d49c7fc417af2b8669/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/regexp/RegexNERSequenceClassifier.java#L228) saying:
"This is pretty deathly slow. It loops over each entry, and then loops over each document token for it."  This is probably why the pipeline approach is slow. Would be nice to be able to disable RegexNER.

Comment: After digging through the code, I found the properties that allow me to turn off the extra annotators, and also found that they were documented in a [migration document](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/migration.html). I'm recording them here for others' benefit: `ner.applyFineGrained` (boolean) controls whether `TokensRegexNERAnnotator` is used, while `ner.buildEntityMentions` (boolean) controls whether `EntityMentionsAnnotator` is used (to give you access to full entity, not just tokens. ex "John", "Smith" becomes "John Smith")